# numpy array with spatial data; quickly get angular velocity?

Tags: python, numpy, vector

I'm storing spatial data in a history in the form of a numpy array. Each row is a 4 dimensional vector where the first column contains a POSIX time stamp and the other three contain the actual spatial data. The spatial vectors are all unit vectors, thus, only have a rotational relation to each other.

Is there some kind of a royal road to how to calculate angular velocity between the entries?

Doing this manually I would one by one calculate the time stamp delta `dt` by `diff`ing the first column and the angle between the entries by something like

```
dt = np.diff(data[:,0])
for i in range(data.shape[0]):
    np.arccos(np.dot(data[i-1,1:], data[i,1:])) / dt[i]
```

But as shown I would do the latter in a for-loop and so was hoping for some fancy one-liner command that could do the same, almost like `diff()`, something like

```
dt = np.diff(data[:,0])
da = np.ang_diff(data[:,1:3]) 
v =  da / dt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to do that with `np.einsum` and some slicing

```
def ang_diff(data):
    return np.arccos(np.einsum('ij,ij->i', data[1:], data[:-1], optimize = True))
```

The rest is pretty much optimized as far as I can see.

Comment: If I put my data in that function I'm getting only NaNs as a result, and the error message `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in arccos`

Comment: Did you strip the time stamps off before (i.e. `ang_diff(data[:,1:3])` from your starting code?)

Comment: I didn't, thanks. And I also forgot to turn my data into unit vectors. Damn tunnel vision...